# How to get the current onChange value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've had help getting this far, and I need a bit more help. Somehow the first click doesn't register anything but an empty array. I'm looking at results from the console logger in the `handleChange` method. The code works wonderfully for going back and changing selections, but I'm unable to validate the form because, at present, I can only see 41 elements in the results.  Please help me out here. Thank you.

**after 4 clicks:** `(0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 0)`

```
click1 > []
click2 > {"0":0}
click3 > {"0":0,"1":1}
click4 > {"0":0,"1":1,"2":2}
```

**how to get value of element clicked as well as other values?**

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Acme extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selections: [],
      statements: /*  Array of 42 strings */
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const [id, value] = event.target.value.split('-')
    this.setState({
      selections: {
          ...this.state.selections,
          [id]: parseInt(value, 10)
      }
    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.selections))
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert('not yet')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Acme</h2>
        <hr />
        <h3>  instructions...  </h3>

        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {
            this.state.statements.map(
              (statement, index) => (

                 <h4> {index+1}. &nbsp; {statement} </h4>

                  <input type="radio" value={`${index}-0`}
                      key={`${index}-0`} id={`${index}-0`}
                      checked={this.state.selections[index] === 0 }
                      onChange={this.handleChange} />
                  <label htmlFor={`${index}-0`}>  0 </label>

                  <input type="radio" value={`${index}-1`}
                      key={`${index}-1`} id={`${index}-1`}
                      checked={this.state.selections[index] === 1}
                      onChange={this.handleChange } />
                  <label htmlFor={`${index}-1`}>  1 </label>

                  <input type="radio" value={`${index}-2`}
                      key={`${index}-2`} id={`${index}-2`}
                      checked={this.state.selections[index] === 2 }
                      onChange={this.handleChange } />
                  <label htmlFor={`${index}-2`}>  2 </label>

                  <input type="radio" value={`${index}-3`}
                      key={`${index}-3`} id={`${index}-3`}
                      checked={this.state.selections[index] === 3 }
                      onChange={this.handleChange } />
                  <label htmlFor={`${index}-3`}>  3 </label>
              )
            )
          }
          <button type="submit"> See Results </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: setState is async so immediately after setState you will not get the updated state value, use setState callback to check the updated values or do console.log inside render method. `setState` callback like this: `this.setState({...}, () => console.log(this.state.selections))`

Comment: another suggestion is, setState is async so instead of using `this.state` inside setState use functional setState (prevState concept), like this: `this.setState(prevState => {....})`